# Move action to the top of the quick fixes list in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I am wondering if I can move some action to the top of the quick fixes list in WebStorm?
Like in screenshot move framed action to the top:
[image]

Comment: you can't, it's not customizable

Comment: Extra hints (on top of Lena's comment). If you need to use that particular fix often and you prefer keyboard navigation, that popup menu supports quick search, so just start typing and it will narrow the list (can be much faster than using Arrow Up/Down for navigation in some cases, especially if menu items may contain different items based on the code/issue).